Пустая область или отступ при запуске Wpf
Недавно начал изучать WPF и появилась такая проблема.
Разместил все нужные элементы на форме, а при запуске они все съезжают.


Я думаю дело в этой пустой области, на которую указывает стрелка, можно как-то её убрать?
<Window x:Name="Recipes" x:Class="Recipes1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Recipes1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="" Height="340" Width="260" ResizeMode="NoResize">
<Grid Margin="0,0,0,0">
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,295,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80"/>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="170,295,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBoxSearch" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="120,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Поиск" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Height="20"/>
    <Button x:Name="buttonSearch" Content="︎" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="230,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="20" Width="20" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Arial"/>
    <ComboBox x:Name="comboBoxFilter" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Height="20"/>
    <ListBox d:ItemsSource="{d:SampleData ItemCount=5}" Margin="10,40,10,40"/>
</Grid>


Нужно избегать абсолютного позиционирования с помощью Margin. Почитайте про компоновку, строки и столбцы в элементе Grid. Начать можно отсюда: https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/4.php
